# UITableViewCell dynamic drawing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with different (amount) subviews for every cell. The amount of subviews comes from the server and is different for every row. Where should I do the drawing? I can't do it within the `UITableViewCell` since it is not possible to pass the height to the `init` method.

Should I do the drawing (that is different for every cell) in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: You should always reuse cells, for performance reasons, update the layout of your cells in willDisplayCell:: Override the initWithStyle method in your UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always reuse cells where possible for performance reasons.

Consult the [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), these provide descriptions to what the methods you mentioned do and how they should be used. Apple says willDisplayCell:

> Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a
> particular row.

You have various height changing methods also available. This is a very broad, design question, that requires some research on your part so you can decide which methods suit your needs

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I want to now where I should draw it since I can't do it in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` because I can not pass the appropriate height to that method. Changing it to e.g. `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:height` doesn't work since I do not manually call it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I made an update to my opening post. Please check it out again.

Comment: You don't customise the cell at initialisation. You always customise a cell based on the datasource, so use the UITableViewDataSource methods at your disposal. You seem to be confused about what overriding means because your question is asking where do you override initWithStyle::, which I answered. Read the class reference to determine where you want to do the drawing - Apple recommends willDisplayCell\

Comment: You are right on the title. I changed it. I read the docs and I am going to do the drawing in `willDisplayCell`. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer to meet your edited question, at the bottom.

Comment: Great. I changed the question to be more useful for future visitors of this page. Would be great if you removed the first part of your answer to only show the updated part so I can accept the answer. ;) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I said removing the first part of your answer. This isn't a right answer. Please change this for the `willDisplayCell` part with the the documentation reference.

Comment: I have removed the first part of the answer. My answer now tells you to read the documentation, and that I recommend willDisplayCell and the other delegate/datasource methods at your disposal.

Comment: In future, be more concise with your question asking to avoid having to make huge edits that cause answers to no longer make sense. You deleted your question about reuse as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39433/discussion-between-yoeriboven-and-jeff)